# Force.com IDE managed Package creation

Tags: managed-package, deployment, force.com-ide

I'm new to force.com IDE, as well salesforce, please clarify me the below doubts

1. How can i create a `manage and unmanaged package` from force.com IDE (from Eclipse)
   by default when i deploy from one org to another org (via IDE - Deploy server menu), its unmanaged package able to read all the apex class from the destination org
2. How can i pull (in IDE) all the apex class from managed package org (assume that org was managed package)

Answer (score 4):

> How can i create a manage and unmanaged package from force.com IDE (from Eclipse) by default when i deploy from one org to another org (via IDE - Deploy server menu), its unmanaged package able to read all the apex class from the destination org

You can't create a managed package in a new org via the Force.com IDE, as that has to be done in the UI. However, until we have DX, you won't be able to share the namespace for your package in multiple developer orgs, so all development orgs except for your packaging org would have to be unmanaged. You can deploy unmanaged packages from the Force.com IDE.

> How can i pull (in IDE) all the apex class from managed package org (assume that org was managed package)

When creating a new Force.com Project, select the "package" option and choose your managed package. It will automatically select all items in your package, and place them in your project.

Comment: `until we have DX, you won't be able to share the namespace for your package in multiple developer orgs`- Good to know about it @sfdcfox, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Would try to answer your queries here:

1. Creation of packages, managed or unmanaged:

   - You cannot create them from IDE.
2. View code in IDE:

   - You can see code from a unmanaged package not for managed one.
   - Unmanaged packages are easier to deploy using links generated after creation in source org, instead of doing it from IDE.

You should refer this document - [An Introduction to Packaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging)

Comment: Thanks for your information, let me know the way of creating the managed package, because we need to deploy in production org with managed package option

Comment: Why would you ever want to deploy to production using a managed package. You would need to do a bit of research as you are new.

Comment: This is a small application with Agile methodology, so we plan to give an demo to client so that..